# Ubuntu fails to install cuda toolkit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda

I want to install cuda toolkit on ubuntu 14.04, so I downloaded `cuda-repo.deb` from nVidia site and then ran:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
```

But it fails. There are no error messages, it just freezes up and that's all. I cancelled the installation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

Afterwards when I try to install something with `apt-get`, I get this message:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I try to execute the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, I get

```
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1404 (6.5-14) ...
```

and then it freezes. Can I fix this problem? Delete this package or something.

**UPDATE**

 i fix my problem, mb it will help to someone:
this deb package try to add repo-key, so in `postinst` there is a string

```
wget -q -O - http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/GPGKEY | apt-key add - || echo "Failed to add GPGKEY at http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/GPGKEY to apt keys."
```

I sit behind the proxy so wget freezes and can't so smth. To solve this problem i do this:
1) export all my proxy settings to env variables(add to `~/.bashrc`)

```
export http_proxy=http://usr:passwd@host:port/
export FTP_PROXY=http://usr:passwd@host:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://usr:passwd@host:port/
export https_proxy=http://usr:passwd@host:port/
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://usr:passwd@host:port/
export HTTP_PROXY=http://usr:passwd@host:port/
```

2) but this script run under `sudo` so you need that this variables should be saved. To do this run `sudo visudo` and add

```
Defaults        env_keep +="http_proxy"
Defaults        env_keep +="https_proxy"
Defaults        env_keep +="HTTP_PROXY"
Defaults        env_keep +="HTTPS_PROXY"
```

After this it should be working.

Comment: Have you installed build-essential and linux headers? Just in case: sudo apt-get build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r); now run *dpkg --configure...* again.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae when i try to `sudo apt-get build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. I just see `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`. And after i run it i have freeze on Setting up `cuda-repo-ubuntu1404 (6.5-14) ...`

Comment: I hit the same problem today with the proxy. Make sure to use `sudo -E` so that your environment is preserved.